# Can rows be pivoted into columns by using a SQL self join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, inner-join, self-join

I needed help in self join for the below mentioned table say datarate_tbl

I need to compare data for two dates say for 18th and 20th date from same table .
I Need to query data to pull data from same table so as to align data for file_size and rate column along side 18th data

[image]

The queried data should look like this

[image]

I tried to write a query using self join but dint worked to get result  data set. Would appreciate any help

I have the query which is giving me extra two rows instead of 5. Problem occurs at net parallel.

```
 select a.date::date ,a.hostname,a.test_type,a.file_size,a.rate ,b.date::date ,b.file_size ,b.rate

from checkperf_allproduct_metrics a

left join(select * from checkperf_allproduct_metrics where date::date = '2020-12-18') b

on a.instance = b.instance

and a.hostname=b.hostname

and a.test_type =b.test_type

where a.instance = 'nytpsg00394'

and a.date::date = '2020-12-20'

;



date    |                        hostname                        |  test_type   | file_size  |    rate     |    date    | file_size  |    rate

------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------

2020-12-20 | abc.com.in                             | disk write   | 1073741824 |      297.67 | 2020-12-18 | 1073741824 |      344.78

2020-12-20 | abc.com.in                             | disk read    | 1073741824 |     3413.33 | 2020-12-18 | 1073741824 |     2438.10

2020-12-20 | abc.com.in                             | stream       |          0 |    15887.52 | 2020-12-18 | 1073741824 |    15116.31

2020-12-20 | abc.com.in-> abc.com.in| Net Parallel |            | 3187.470000 | 2020-12-18 | 1073741824 | 3285.460000

2020-12-20 | abc.com.in-> abc.com.in| Net Parallel |            | 3187.470000 | 2020-12-18 | 1073741824 | 3215.270000

2020-12-20 | abc.com.in-> abc.com.in| Net Parallel |            | 3163.380000 | 2020-12-18 | 1073741824 | 3285.460000

2020-12-20 | abc.com.in-> abc.com.in| Net Parallel |            | 3163.380000 | 2020-12-18 | 1073741824 | 3215.270000
```

Problem occurs in Net Parallel column actually. If you can help me fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select hostname, test_type,
    max(file_size) filter(where date = date '2020-12-18') as file_size_18,
    max(rate) filter(where date = date '2020-12-18') as rate_18,
    max(file_size) filter(where date = date '2020-12-20') as file_size_20,
    max(rate) filter(where date = date '2020-12-20') as rate_20
from mytable t
where date in (date '2020-12-18', date '2020-12-20')
group by hostname, test_type
```

Comment: Thank you so much GMB for the response. 2nd one is very close but I had the same problem which it is giving some rows are duplicated. Well the first option may not work in postgress. Could you help to give query iin postgress

Comment: @Asrar: the second query would not produce duplicates for your sample data. As for the first one, this is supported syntax in Postgres. Give it a try (I just updated id)

Comment: Dint helped me GMB 2nd one is giving me two rows extra which i want to avoid.

Comment: FIrst one dint gave desired results. I have done edit if you can help me to fix the query to get 5 rows as posted in the desired data set

Comment: @Asrar: use the first query. I removed the other one. I guarantees one row per hostname and testtype

Comment: HI GMB , It is returning me 8 rows instead of 5 and and giving duplicates on test_type

Comment: I am posting the details as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using max with the filter function in the sql query like this.

```
select hostname, test_type,

    max(file_size) filter(where date::date = date '2020-12-18') as file_size_18,

    max(rate) filter(where date::date = date '2020-12-18') as rate_18,

    max(file_size) filter(where date::date = date '2020-12-20') as file_size_20,

    max(rate) filter(where date::date = date '2020-12-20') as rate_20

from checkperf_allproduct_metrics t

where date::date in (date '2020-12-18', date '2020-12-20')

group by hostname, test_type;
```

Output

```
                      hostname                        |  test_type   | file_size_18 |   rate_18   | file_size_20 |   rate_20

--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------

abc.com.in                             | disk read    |              |             |   1073741824 |     2925.71

abc.com.in                             | disk write   |              |             |   1073741824 |      449.12

abc.com.in                             | stream       |              |             |            0 |    15354.96

abc.com.in->abc.com.in| Net Parallel |              |             |              | 3164.820000

abc.com.in                             | disk read    |   1073741824 |     2438.10 |   1073741824 |     3413.33

abc.com.in                             | disk write   |   1073741824 |      344.78 |   1073741824 |      297.67

abc.com.in                             | stream       |   1073741824 |    15116.31 |            0 |    15887.52

abc.com.in-> abc.com.in| Net Parallel |   1073741824 | 3285.460000 |              | 3187.470000
```

Comment: I think you hostname or type has some records with spaces. Try using trim on both in group by and select.